# Condition In MouseEvent C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, mouseevent

I am new to C# and trying to make small Program, that should continue if 2  conditions are give. The first one if mouse is click on load page and second if mousehover on shape. That should give me location of shape if both conditions are true

What i tried is here

```
Bool load = false;

 Private void Form1_MouseDown (object sender , MouseEventArgs e) 
 {
     load = true;
 }

Private void rectangleShape2_MouseEnter (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   If (load == true)
     {
        textbox1.Text = rectangleShape2.location.Tostring();
      }
 }
```

But it didnt worked

Comment: What didn't work? Did you get an exception? If so, what was it?

Comment: I expected  that it will give me shape location while pressing down button on load page and hovering on shape.. but it is giving me location of shape after clicking on load page and then hovering on shape

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using the incorrect event on mouse. You have to use MouseLeftButtonDown or MouseRightButtonDown event and not MouseDown.